# Django Failed to install index for?

Tags: python, mysql, django, fedora

When trying to migrate my django site to a fedora server and trying to run python manage.py syncdb/ test results in the following errors. How should I proceed to determine what is causing these errors?

```
ceramic@astro1: ~/tmn_project >> python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Failed to install index for admin.LogEntry model: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibj971An' (Errcode: 2)")
Failed to install index for auth.Permission model: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/iboMFLon' (Errcode: 2)")
Failed to install index for auth.Group_permissions model: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibIrTwdn' (Errcode: 2)")
Failed to install index for auth.User_groups model: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ib0aTc3m' (Errcode: 2)")
Failed to install index for auth.User_user_permissions model: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibnGiNTm' (Errcode: 2)")
Failed to install index for sessions.Session model: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibABciLm' (Errcode: 2)")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

The account has access to /tmp/ but no sudo permissions. Thanks.

Comment: do you have read and write permission or just read?

Comment: | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ceramic'@'localhost'                           
    | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ceramic_database`.* TO 'ceramic'@'localhost'

Comment: For the /tmp/ directory there is read and write permissions.